# How to pass db information into fragment?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I'm a newbie, so don't be harsh.
I want to build something like in this picture:

[image]

But I was wondering, how could I store "Picture names" (strings) into a DB and from there add them to fragments (ListFragments - picture + name). I'm using recycler view (I know I can accomplish this by not using fragments, but I'm trying to learn them exactly right now, this is just an example for my understanding).

I've DB like:

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME="CategoryDatabase";

public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

}

@Override

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {

    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Category (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT);");

}

@Override

public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Category");

    onCreate(db);

}

public void addCategory(String name)

{

    ContentValues values=new ContentValues(1);

    values.put("name", name);

    getWritableDatabase().insert("Category", "name", values);

}

public Cursor getCategories()

{

    Cursor cursor = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select * from Category", null);

    return cursor;

}

}
```

Adding categories to DB:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    databaseHelper = new MyDatabaseHelper(this);
    // Adding categories to DB.
    databaseHelper.addCategory("Example1");
    databaseHelper.addCategory("John");
    databaseHelper.addCategory("Michael");

}
```

Is this okay? If so, how can I retrieve DB info in fragments (displayed in RecyclerView)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The first step here is going to be sitting down and clearly defining your database schema. Also, be *very* careful with adding terms - e.g `"CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_NAME` as if you concatenate that way, the system will not be able to distinguish data from code, leading to a SQL vulnerability.

Comment: @Ares Hey, I'll look into it. I edited my post, can u check it out, please and possibly answer? :)

Comment: Please go through this nice example, http://www.journaldev.com/9438/android-sqlite-database-example-tutorial

Comment: @PonsuyambuVelladurai Thanks for suggestion. Did that. I'm still kinda confused how to get database information out in fragments.

Comment: @ThingsILove1996 read this https://guides.codepath.com/android/Local-Databases-with-SQLiteOpenHelper
Basically, you just need to make a query on your database and then populate your adapter with data that you got from the cursor.